# VB.NET ActiveDocument.Hyperlink Command failed when adding hyperlinks

Tags: vb.net

When i try to add an hyperlink to the activedocument I get the exception "Command failed" every single time. I added `word.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor:=word.Selection, Address:="www.google.com", TextToDisplay:="TEST")`  to add an hyperlink to the existing document with an alias. But it doesn't seem to work and the exception, inner exception and stacktrace ar not of any help at all.

```
 Dim word As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application = CreateObject("Word.Application")
                word.Documents.Add(documentProperty.Filename)

                If Not IO.Directory.Exists(documentProperty.SaveAsFilename.Substring(0, documentProperty.SaveAsFilename.LastIndexOf("\"))) Then
                    IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(documentProperty.SaveAsFilename.Substring(0, documentProperty.SaveAsFilename.LastIndexOf("\")))
                End If

                word.Visible = False
                word.PrintPreview = False
                word.ScreenUpdating = False
                word.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor:=word.Selection, Address:="www.google.com", TextToDisplay:="TEST")
                word.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(OutputFileName:=documentProperty.SaveAsFilename,
                                                        ExportFormat:=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF,
                                                        OpenAfterExport:=False,
                                                        OptimizeFor:=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForPrint,
                                                        Range:=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportRange.wdExportAllDocument,
                                                        From:=1,
                                                        To:=1,
                                                        Item:=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportItem.wdExportDocumentContent,
                                                        IncludeDocProps:=True,
                                                        KeepIRM:=True,
                                                        CreateBookmarks:=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportCreateBookmarks.wdExportCreateNoBookmarks,
                                                        DocStructureTags:=True,
                                                        BitmapMissingFonts:=True,
                                                        UseISO19005_1:=False)
```

Comment: In your code the selection is not set and I think you need to use Selection.Range

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the anchor parameter. You want to be using word.Selection.Range instead of word.Selection.